# broken animation in portfolio filter without plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

html code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="wp">
    <span name="all">all</span>
    <span name="web">web design</span>
    <span name="php">php</span>
    <span name="wordpress">wordpress</span>
    <span name="html">html</span>
</div>
    <ul>
        <li name="web">web design</li>
        <li name="wordpress">wordpress</li>
        <li name="php">php</li>
        <li name="html">html</li>
        <li name="wordpress">wordpress</li>
        <li name="php">php</li>
        <li name="html">html</li>
        <li name="web">web design</li>
        <li name="web">web design</li>
        <li name="html">html</li>
        <li name="php">php</li>
        <li name="html">html</li>
        <li name="php">php</li>
        <li name="wordpress">wordpress</li>
        <li name="web">web design</li>
        <li name="wordpress">wordpress</li>
        <li name="web">web design</li>
        <li name="html">html</li>
        <li name="php">php</li>
        <li name="wordpress">wordpress</li>
        <li name="wordpress">wordpress</li>
        <li name="html">html</li>
        <li name="php">php</li>
        <li name="wordpress">wordpress</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Css(with scss)

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

body{
    padding: 50px;
}

$col1: #ff3030;
$col2: lightblue;
$col3: lightgreen;

span{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid $col1;
    background: $col1 + #111;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: arial;
}

.wp{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;

}

li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: $col3 - #111;
    border: 1px solid $col3 - #222;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 40px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr1 = [],
        arr2 = [],
        arr3 = [],
        arr4 = [];
    $('li').each(function(i, el) {
        if($(el).attr('name') == 'web') {
            arr1.push(el);
        } else if($(el).attr('name') == 'wordpress') {
            arr2.push(el);
        } else if($(el).attr('name') == 'php') {
            arr3.push(el);
        } else if($(el).attr('name') == 'html') {
            arr4.push(el);
        }
    });

    $('span').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            elems = $('li');
        if( $this.attr('name') == 'all') {
            elems.fadeIn();
            return false
        }  else if ($this.attr('name') == 'web') {
            elems.fadeOut(600);
            setTimeout(function() {$(arr1).fadeIn(600);
            }, 800);
        }  else if ($this.attr('name') == 'wordpress') {
            elems.fadeOut(600);
            setTimeout(function() {$(arr2).fadeIn(600);
            }, 800);
        }  else if ($this.attr('name') == 'php') {
            elems.fadeOut(600);
            setTimeout(function() {$(arr3).fadeIn(600);
            }, 800);
        }  else if ($this.attr('name') == 'html') {
            elems.fadeOut(600);
            setTimeout(function() {$(arr4).fadeIn(600);
            }, 800);
        }
    });

});
```

fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/qyY7T/
Or full screen
http://jsfiddle.net/qyY7T/embedded/result/

The problem is in animate effect, which doesn't work... As you can see, I have already set a Timout, but no resaults. I'll thanx to everybody, and ask you - don't give any plugins. Thanx!

Comment: Try looping elems like `elems.each(function() { // animate here });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you can't fadeout a li so you have to do the ul here is what I mean:

```
window.arr0 = [],
window.arr1 = [],
window.arr2 = [],
window.arr3 = [],
window.arr4 = [];
$('li').each(function (i, el) {
    arr0.push(el);
    if ($(el).attr('name') == 'web') {
        arr1.push(el);
    } else if ($(el).attr('name') == 'php') {
        arr2.push(el);
    } else if ($(el).attr('name') == 'wordpress') {
        arr3.push(el);
    } else if ($(el).attr('name') == 'html') {
        arr4.push(el);
    }
});
$('span').click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $('ul').fadeOut(600);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('li').css('display', 'none');
        $(window['arr' + $this.attr('name')]).each(function() {
            this.style.display = 'block';
        });
        $('ul').fadeIn();
    }, 600);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qyY7T/1/